# How do I line break X509 certificate string?

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

Typically, when a X509 certificate file is downloaded from another site, it consists of several lines.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDETCCAfmgAwIBAgIJAI+TpAQ6jj2zMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMB8xHTAbBgNV
BAoMFE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiwgQ049TFNHMB4XDTIwMDUxODA1MjQxNloXDTIwMDYx
...
```

*Do you have any criteria for break the line? Or should I just break the line to look good?*

I have a one-line certificate string encoded Base64.
This certificate file is intended to be downloaded from the web.

Regards Me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) and [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2):

> Generators MUST wrap the base64-encoded lines so that each line consists of **exactly 64 character**s except for the final line, which will encode the remainder of the data (within the 64-character line boundary), and they MUST NOT emit extraneous whitespace.  Parsers MAY handle other line sizes. These requirements are consistent with PEM [RFC1421].

Comment: I found this because I was trying to be clever and (among other "improvements") bunched up my certificate into one big string. The server didn't like my client and took me some time to figure out that I need a new line every 64 chars. '\n' did the job in my case. Honestly a little disappointed they would impose a visual constraint like that... Which you'd have to read the x509 spec to know about... And RFCs are ridiculously bad for people who are not native English speakers :(